# How to make the variable available without creating instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables, static-variables

I have this wierd situation. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the outlook of my class structure:

```
class A
  def 1_function a1
    call_c
  end

  def 2_function 
    call_c
  end

  def call_c
    if a1 present 
      do this
    else
      do this
    end
  end
end

class B
  A.1_function a1
end

class C
  A.2_function
end
```

Here in `call_c` I need to check if that parameter a1 is present or not. I cannot add default paramter in `call_c` since there are many functions actually intermediate between `1_function`, `2_function` and `call_c` (hence I would end up changing a lot)

Method 1:
I could create a @ variable in my class. But this would break atomicity and its inappropriate to maintain state using static variables.

Please suggest me any other alternative.

Comment: I see you have a really high rep with a lot of Rails experience, so I'm a little surprised by the coding example.  Would you mind updating it to something without syntax errors?  And did you really mean to send an instance method name to class A from classes B and C?  Also, @variables are not static variables, they are instance variables. Is that what you meant to say?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand your question, but if this really is a class and the methods in `A` are really instance methods, then there's really nothing inherently wrong with storing `a1` in an instance variable and referencing it from `call_c`.  BTW, I'm assuming that `1_function`, `2_function` and `call_c` are all supposed to be method names, the illegal syntax of the former two notwithstanding.